# Websupergoo abcpdf is truncating end of page data when generate large pdf from HTML

Tags: pdf-generation, gecko

The company has WebSuperGoo Abcpdf version 9

I've switched the engine from Gecko to MSHtml and this fixed the issue but altered the formatting of the text enough to get complaints, so I've gone back to Gecko and I'm trying to figure out the HTML text truncation. I tried modifying my

`pdf.Rect.Inset(45, 105);`

values to adjust the page size but this doesn't solve the problem. 
I'm in a secure environment so I can't display pdf data here. 
My HTML has large textarea's that are getting truncated (whole paragraphs are missing!!)
and page breaking is happening in funny places often 
leaving whole pages blank, when utilizing Gecko engine.

The HTML is being passed in via a response from a service call and would be 
difficult to modify and the PDF creation is another global call that 
works for other shorter reports.

Any suggestions on changes would be helpful I've been working on this for days
now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to fix text truncation in WebSuperGoo Abcpdf version 9 if  you are using textarea you should probably execute the following:

var newData = sourceData.Replace("textarea", "span");

then style the span similarly to the textarea